# What is this tic-tac-toe like game with green and yellow balls?

Tags: identify-this-game

I found recently this board game in my parents' home (Spain); it seems like it might possibly be a version of tic-tac-toe.

Does anybody know the name of the game or the rules?

[image]

Comment: The 24 spaces (counting the holes) and the line connections make me thnik that it is of the morris family. But I've never seen a morris variation that used two boards.

Comment: The board looks pretty home made, but how many of the green/yellow counters are present?
It's possible the holes are ways to remove already placed pieces

Comment: I'm thinking could there be more boards?  Maybe it can be arranged different way.  there are thin lines coming off some circles to edge of blocks.

Comment: Looks like a variation of Chinese Checkers to me.

Comment: It looks almost like a two-player version of pachisi: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pachisi - the lines on the board could be the path around the board; in that case green has two home already. What argues against that are the lines disappearing off the sides of the board. (Two on one side, one on the other). Are both boards identical? Are there any markings on the other side of the boards?